# How To update contextMenu after it shows in flex

Tags: apache-flex, refresh, contextmenu, reload

The thing is I load context menu items dynamically and it takes time to load, so context menu appears with default values the first time. But if you right-click again, yo see the loaded values.

Is there a way to refresh items while the menu is still opened?
or someway to reload it?

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  All you can do is set the menu items right before it displays.